# Getting return value from oracle function using SimpleJdbcCall

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I have Oracle function defined as:

```
function get_user_by_term (inUserTerm number) return number;
```

Now I wan to call this function using Spring SimpleJdbCCall but not sure how I can read return value since I don't have out param in function. I can't change the Oracle function code.

Code I have so far in Java is:

```
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
        .withSchemaName("SCHMA").withCatalogName("PKG_USER")
        .withProcedureName("get_user_by_term");
Map<String, Object> inParamMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
inParamMap.put("inUserTerm ", userTermId );
SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource(inParamMap);
simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);
```

Comment: Spring Documentation covers it here: [3.5.8. Calling a stored function using SimpleJdbcCall](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#jdbc-simple-jdbc-call-3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After research I found following:

1. Instead of `withProcedureName()` method `withFunctionName()` method should be used.
2. Instead of `execute()` method use `executeFunction()` with return type parameter.

So complete code be like

```
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
        .withSchemaName("SCHMA").withCatalogName("PKG_USER")
        .withFunctionName("get_user_by_term");
Map<String, Object> inParamMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
inParamMap.put("inUserTerm ", userTermId );
SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource(inParamMap);
Long userId = simpleJdbcCall.executeFunction(BigDecimal.class, in).longValue();
```

Hope this will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

Calling executeFunction on the call worked for me, while i had to keep ".withProcedureName(...)" as it was. Check out your updated code:

```
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
     .withSchemaName("SCHMA")
     .withCatalogName("PKG_USER")
     .withProcedureName("get_user_by_term");
MapSqlParameterSource inParams = new MapSqlParameterSource()
     .addValue("inUserTerm ", userTermId );

Long returnVal = simpleJdbcCall.executeFunction(BigDecimal.class, inParams).longValue();
```